# Overloading methods

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I  saw  below  question  posted  on  this site.

`"What happens when we pass int arguments to the overloading method having float` `as a parameter for one method and another having double param".`

I  thought  I  understood  the  concept and wrote this code:

```
public  class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        TestClass t=new TestClass();

        t.sum(1/4);
    }
    void sum(double d)
    {
        System.out.println("Double==="+d);
    }
    void sum(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("Integer==="+i);
    }
    void sum(short s)
    {
        System.out.println("Short==="+d);
    }
}
```

According  to  my  understanding  explained  on  this  site (as  mentioned above),  I  thought  it  will  print  `Short===0`,  but  to  my  surprise  it  prints  `Integer===0`.  Can  any  one  explain  this  to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't **explicitly** tell the compiler what are the types of `1` and `4`, it assumes they are of type `int`. Then, `/` operator will apply integer division and will produce another `int` (which will be `0`.)

After that, the method with the most *specific to integer* parameter type will be invoked. In your case, this will be `sum(int i)`.

If you want to invoke some of the other overloaded methods, you will have to explicitly:

- do a cast. For example, `sum((short) (1/4));` will invoke `sum(short s)` due to the cast.
- point the type of the operands. For example, `sum(1d/4)` will invoke `sum(double d)`, since `1d/4` will result to `double`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, these are overloaded methods, not overridden methods.

`1` and `4` are integers. Therefore `1/4` is an integer division, returning `0`.

Therefore, the method being called is `sum(int i)`.

`sum(short s)` would never be called for an int parameter, since that would require a [narrowing primitive conversion (JLS 5.1.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), that may cause data loss, and is not allowed in [method invocation conversion (JLS 5.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3). Such a conversion can be done with an explicit cast.

If you remove the int version, `sum(double d)` would be called, and if you remove the double version, the code won't compile.

In order to call the short version, you must cast the parameter to short :

```
t.sum ((short)(1/4));
```

Answer (score 0):

For integer number, the type `int` is a default choice. So, although 1 and 4 can be defined as both `int` or `short`, since you did not defined anything, the compiler identified 1 and 4 as `int` and therefore it entered into the function for 1/4 division (0), which took the parameter `int`.